# JaxRS regular expression in Path

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using JaxRS and I want to put a regex for a path variable.

```
@Path("/{environment : (?i)(zee|bar|foo)) }/{type : (123|1234)}")
```

Now it is pretty clear what I want.

ZEE or zee, BAR or bar, FOO or foo, along with any other fOo, bAr, etc etc case insensitive word.

Same with `type`, just take 123 or 1234

My regex is failing, it compiles but I am getting a 404, for a url like:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/test/fOo/123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't you have an extra closing parenthesis in `(?i)(zee|bar|foo))` ?

Comment: for some reason intellij did not warn me